# Memcached + PHP storing data and fetching + Unique IP counter + Referrer

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

i want make an unique counter which tracks following, every referrer and ip from where the user comes. Memcached should store that data and than it should be entered into the database after 5 mins or so. And also it should check for duplicate entries that not twice the ip is written to the DB

I have an idea to do it without memcache, but than every sec something would be written into the database which would make the site slow.

I can cache basic SQL with memcache but i have no clue how make that above, just learned coding. So im a totally noob :)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: if your using Apache, it will be in the Apache access log, why not use it.

Comment: if your using the data for stats there are many scripts that do that using the Apache access log, or google analytics is popular.

Comment: aha, and how i would do that? would that also faster than doing it like how i want do it above?

Comment: well i want do a trading system, i need that data in db, no thrid party tracking

Comment: which,  there are 3 options i gave you, pass the log file your self, install something that passes it or use google analytics

Comment: Parsing log files will become troublesome if you use more then 1 server. Better store it in the database. I'm pretty sure there is an Apache plugin that will allow you to log directly to a database but you are still facing same write throughput issues as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it - you are using a RDBMS to store the information for long term. I can suggest 2 things:

**1. Store information in key/value store such as Memcached and write it to RDBMS periodically through a background process (CRON job).**
With this solution you would do something like this in your application code:

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$m->setOption(Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION, false);
$m->append('some_unique_id', '|' . time() . ':' . base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
```

And then you would have a CRON job doing something like this:

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

foreach($list_of_unique_ids as $uid)
{
    $raw_data = $m->get($uid);
    $m->delete($uid);

    $uid_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);

    $items = explode('|', $raw_data);
    $sql = array();
    foreach($items as $rec)
    {
        if (!empty($rec))
        {
            list($timestamp, $ref_base64) = explode(':', $rec, 2);
            $ref = base64_decode($ref_base64);
            $ref_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($ref);

            $sql[] = "('" . $uid_safe . "', " . (int) $timestamp . ", '" . $ref_safe . "')";
        }
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO some_table (user_id, ts, ref) VALUES " . implode(',', $sql));
}
```

**2. Use a more advanced key/value store such as Redis or MongoDB as primary means of long-term storage.**
Just pick a database engine with huge write throughput and call it a day.

Comment: thank you for your answer yeah that was looking for, but now i recognize after googling why that append command not working, I have "memcache" not memcached installed on my xampp server and dedicated server (found out that it gives two different versions :( ). I checked php.net for memcache append but had no luck, do you know if such command gives for memcache

Comment: Honestly, this solution is FAR from ideal. I suggest using MongoDB method instead.

Comment: thank you, i just made it other, i write all data in a txt file and use a cronjob to delete / update the data update the mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

```
> i want make an unique counter which
> tracks following, every referrer and
> ip from where the user comes.
> Memcached should store that data and
> than it should be entered into the
> database after 5 mins or so. And also
> it should check for duplicate entries
> that not twice the ip is written to
> the DB
```

I would advise you to use [redis](http://redis.io) to implement this because redis has all the commands needed to do this [efficiently](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) and has [persistent](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) snapshots. To count you simply use the [incrby](http://redis.io/commands/incrby)/[incr](http://redis.io/commands/incr) => [decr](http://redis.io/commands/decr)/[decbry](http://redis.io/commands/decrby) commands.

If you installed memcached on your box, then installing redis is going to be a sinch. Just `make` will be enough. A popular client to connect to redis from PHP is [predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis/).

If you can not install software you also have the option to use the free plan(5 MB memory, 1 Database, but no backups) from http://redistogo.com. Than you need to do the backups to MySQL manually because snapshots are disabled with free plan(probably better of getting a dedicated box or buying mini plan for $5/month).